# Show remaining wordpress categories in drop down menu

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have limited space for horizontal category navigation bar on top of my theme and I need to limit number of categories shown on this bar and tell WordPress put "More.." as a drop down menu link at the end of the list to let users hover their mouse cursors on that to see other categories as shown in screenshot.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what function you're using to format the navigation menu. It's probably `wp_list_categories()` which might not be the best choice in your case. As @Andre mentioned in his answer, you might want to go with navigation menus available since WordPress 3, but if you need to stick to categories, try `get_categories()` which will return the categories in a non-formatted way. This will enable you to loop through them in any way that you want, include a counter to limit the general output, and then loop through the rest under the More submenu.

Reference: [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using wordpress version 3+.

This is probably not the cleanest way but should work:

- Register a [custom menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to your template. Watch the 'depth' parameter (because you want the second level)
- Go to 'Appearance - Menus'
- Create a Custom Menu
- Create a 'Custom Link' called 'More...'
- add the 'More...' Link with the other categories as sub-categories to the menu.
- write your CSS code to only display the second level on hover.

However, I'm not sure if you want the 'More..' menu item to be a linkpage/category. All of that is possible, just add the category/page instead of the 'Custom Link'.

Hope this workaround can solve your problem.